# Trigger send mail with inner join

Tags: sql-server

I've got 2 tables, `Products` and `Gallery`

```
Products
-----------
ID
Item_Name

Gallery
----------
Item_Id
Description
```

I'm trying to write a simple INSERT trigger on Gallery that does this - each time an INSERT is done into Gallery will be send a email.

Use this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.whatever
ON dbo.wherever
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @body += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(Description) FROM inserted;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE speed > 100)
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @recipients = 'whoever@yourcompany.com', 
          @profile_name = 'default',
          @subject = 'At least one person was speeding', 
          @body = @body;
    END
END
GO
```

But how improve the `@BODY` so i can use `Description from Gallery` and `Item_Name from Products`??

Have ready query, but dont know how to put it together

```
select a.Item_Name, b.Description
FROM dbo.Gallery a
inner join dbo.Products b on a.Item_Id=b.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your trigger is on the `Gallery` table, you can just join the `Inserted` table to `Products` to get the desired result, assuming your current join is correct.

```
SELECT P.Item_Name, I.Description
FROM Inserted AS I
INNER JOIN dbo.Products AS P ON I.Item_Id = P.ID
```

This will return the newly inserted description, with the appropriate item name, but only if the item exists in `Products`.

You can then set the `@body` like so;

```
SELECT @body += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Item Name: ' + P.Item_Name + ', Description: ' + RTRIM(I.Description)
FROM Inserted AS I
INNER JOIN dbo.Products AS P ON I.Item_Id = P.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have almost do it:

```
select @body += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(Description) 
FROM inserted a
inner join dbo.Products b 
    on a.Item_Id=b.ID
```

You need to use the `inserted` table as a `JOIN` table. It has the same structure as your `dbo.Gallery` table but holds only the new inserted records.